# Combining MapInfo records with a duplicate value

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have a MapInfo table with a lot of points in it. The points are clustered together - they represent the first part of a post code, so they're in a similar position but not identical.

What I would like to do is combine the duplicate rows and attach a single point to each row that represents the rough centre of the other points.

In fact, making the centroid for a record is easy, so my real question is how do you combine rows that have a duplicate field?

There are about 1.5 million rows so doing anything by hand is a no-no!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's really easy.

There's a built in function called ["Combine Objects Using Column..."](http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/techsupp/miprod.nsf/kbase_by_product/A112381580BB24DF85256C54004DEC03)